# How to set route for edit in yajra datatables

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I am fetching data in yajra DT  and add the column for edit and delete but don't understand how to set route and get the id from url to edit that specific employee.

```
public function fullEmp(){
    $data=employees::select('*')->orderBy('employee_id','DESC');

    return Datatables::of($data)->addColumn('action', function ($data) {
        return '<a href="'.action('employee@employeeedit', ['user' => $data->id]).'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-1">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>';
    })->make(true);
}
```

this code showing that this url is not defined. i am confuse that how to define it

Comment: Do you really have a controller named `employee` with an action called `employeeedit` (with everything written in lower case)? Is the route parameter really called `user` and not `employee`?

Comment: yes the controller and action name are correct everything is written in lower case and the parameter is here i using to getting the employee id only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted you can try something like that in your `routes/web.php` file:

```php
Route::get('/employees/{user}/edit', 'employee@employeeedit');
```

Comment: you're welcome, please consider also upvoting the answer you find it useful

Comment: It's better if you open another question with the relevant code to leave that clean for others with similar problem

Comment: want to add multiple columns but it's showing the html code ....in the given code

Comment: Please open a new question with the code it gives you the error. This is not a Forum but a Q&A site.

Comment: dude, can you please tell me how to add multiple parameter in given route i have to pass employee name and its id 

Route::get('/employees/{user}&{id}/edit', 'employee@employeeedit');    >> not working

Route::get('/employees/{user}/{id}/edit', 'employee@employeeedit');    >> not working

Comment: @guzu open a new question with the relevant code, comments are not the place to answer to this type of questions.